# how to reduce response time of youtube api

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am using webview in my iOS application to embed the youtube video using ytplayer api, its taking about 5 secs to load the  video, all I want is to reduce the response time of the player,is there a way to achieve it?
I need the response time approximately equal to 2 secs

Answer (score 0):

You mean increasing the response time? Because decreasing means your app is going to take **longer** time to run than usual. Anyway, embedding a YouTube video is different when running the official YouTube application. The problem is with the WebView. Please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23931387/3288182).